# Creating custom init method for UIView to add a UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, ios7, uilabel

At the moment I have a custom UIView class which completes the following:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        [self setupView];
    }
    return self;
}
-(void)setupView {
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 4;
    self.layer.masksToBounds= YES;
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.layer.borderWidth = 1;
    self.layer.borderColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
}
```

I also have another UIView Category that creates a new UIView and makes it so that I can use autolayout which is the following:

```
@implementation UIView (Autolayout)
+(id)autolayoutView
{
    UIView *view = [self new];
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    return view;
}
```

Both are fairly simple. What I would like to do now is create a custom init method for the UIView.

**Question**
I would like the custom init method to be used to create a UILabel and it to the UIView. However, I would like the init method to use the UIView category that I have already created? I am sure this is fairly simple, just not sure how to complete this?

**EDIT**
At present to create a custom autolayout view I call `UIView *myView = [MyCustomViewClass autoLayoutView]`
What I would like to do is update the custom view class init method to create a label, but still have it called in the same way so that the category is being used and I get the auto layout information being called too.

**EDIT 2**
What would be really useful is if I could pass in a parameter to determine if the `UIView` should have a `UILabel`. So a custom init method that could be called if the view should have a label. I know the code to create and add a label/constraints I am just not to sure on the subclassing/category link and creating custom init methods. As well as how this is called in conjunction with the `autoLayoutView` call?

Comment: It's kind of unclear, do you want to add the label from within the category or the init method? And do you want to call the category from within the UIView class or from another Controller or something?

Comment: @Eric - I have added an edit which hopefully clarifies what I am trying to achieve. I am sure its simple but I would like to fully understand the approach.

Comment: Also added a further edit to explain my difficulty in understanding and confusion here. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with this approach is that you are using a category on a generic UIView to create the UIView with `UIView *myView = [MyCustomViewClass autoLayoutView]`.

Since it's a UIView and not the custom subclass you made, it won't have reference to any custom init methods you make. So one solution would be... Why not add all the customization into the category?

```
+(id)autolayoutViewWithCustomization:(BOOL)customize addLabel:(BOOL)addLabel
{
    UIView *view = [self new];
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    if (customize) {
       view.layer.cornerRadius = 4;
       view.layer.masksToBounds= YES;
       view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
       view.layer.borderWidth = 1;
       view.layer.borderColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
    }

    if (addLabel) {
       // Create a label here
       [self addSubview:label];
    }

    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If what i'm getting from your question is correct, then this is what you want to do:

just use the already created init method that you have, and add more onto it.

```
 +(id)autolayoutViewWithAddedLabel:(BOOL)addedLabel
 {  
     UIView *view = [self new];
     view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

     if(addedLabel) {
        // do your label stuff here
        [self addSubview://label];
     }
     return view;
 }
```

then if you wanted to call this method, you could do just as you had done with the method in your question by saying

```
  MyClass *mc = [MyClass autolayoutViewWithAddedLabel:YES];
```

and that'll add the label onto your custom view

hope that helps!